# Как выполнить кроссдоменный обмен json?

Tags: jquery, json, javascript, cross-origin

Пытался сделать запрос к статусу посылки на

http://www.russianpost.ru/tracking20/OperationHistory.js.aspx?Id=RF224661454SG&Code=93985&Language=Russian

Каптчу брал тут http://www.russianpost.ru/tracking20/Code/Code.png.ashx

Делал через jquery (get.json), не получается. Посоветовали Yui от Yahoo. Подскадите, каким образом лучше это сделать?

Comment: @Korobok, http://www.russianpost.ru/ - это ваш сервер или сторонний?

Comment: > Делал через jquery (get.json), не получается.

Что именно не получается?

Comment: Сервер сторонний. Нет ответа. Может как то JSONP использовать он вроде кроссдоменные запросы делать позволяет.

Comment: [Выполнить ajax post запрос с параметрами используя YQL](http://hashcode.ru/questions/305542/jquery-выполнить-ajax-post-запрос-с-параметрами-используя-yql)

Comment: @Korobok, JSONP невозможен без желания сервера, к которому обращаются

Comment: так может javascript -> php -> cross domain и обратно ?

Comment: Попробую через YQL. Позже отпишусь.

Comment: Пробовал подставлять URL здесь http://jsfiddle.net/ivanovsuper/HA3Wn/. Ноль эмоций. Или я что то не правильно делаю.

Comment: Сделал чуть по другому. Теперь этот URL отдает http://www.trackchecker.ru/tracking/dotrack.php?tn=RF224661454SG

Новая проблема. Как получить только последний индекс. То есть индекс где посылка находится в данный момент.

Comment: Самый простой вариант, при условии, что ответ у вас в переменной **obj**  

    obj.events.pop()